# Oledb connection SQL command

Tags: vb.net, oledb

```
Private Sub Myconnection()

    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Users.accdb")
    con.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub Login_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Myconnection()
End Sub

Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
    Dim userTable As New DataTable
    Myconnection()
    adapt = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Registered Users Where User Name='" & UserNameTextBox.Text & "'And Password='" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'", con)
    adapt.Fill(userTable)

    If userTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Login Succesful")

    Else
        MsgBox("User Name Or Password Is invalid")
    End If
End Sub
```

When i run the above code, Currently i am getting this error "Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'User Name='User'And Password='password''." how should i change my code to make it work

Comment: `Select * From [Registered Users] Where [User Name]='" & UserNameTextBox.Text & "'And [Password]='" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'"`. Please consider using parameters though.

Comment: ...because if table names have spaces they have to be escaped and `Password` is a reserved word in Access SQL.  But that code is creating a new connection each time - you are going to run out evetntually.  Use a global connection string, then create, use and dispose of it each time.

Comment: also, you should never, ever store passwords as plain text

Answer (score 0):

This should work, here I'm using a class with a function which accepts a user name and password which is passed to the command using parameters. No need for a DataTable, simple use HasRows to determine if data has been returned.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class DataOperations
    Private Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
        {
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
            .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Users.accdb")
        }
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determine if a user and password are located in the Registered Users table.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="UserName">User name</param>
    ''' <param name="UserPassword">user password</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function IsValidUser(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal UserPassword As String) As Boolean
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [User Name] FROM [Registered Users] WHERE [User Name] = @UserName AND [Password] = @Password"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", UserPassword)
                cn.Open()
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim result = reader.HasRows
                reader.Close()
                Return result
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage

```
Dim ops As New DataOperations
If ops.IsValidUser(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Known user")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Guards, intruder alert!!!")
End If
```